# How can I pick only once a value from spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner with ten numbers 0-10 and I if someone picks a number I want him not to be able to pick the same value again. So inside ItemSelected I do the following with no result

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            if (position > 0 && position!=tempPosition)
            {
                TeamSpinnerNumber = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
             tempPosition = position
            }


        }
```

Comment: "I want him not to be able to pick the same value again" do you mean removing the value from the spinner?

Comment: yes this is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this i worked out for you may it help you.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ArrayList<String> mStrings;
        ArrayAdapter<String> mStringArrayAdapter;
        Spinner mSpinner;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            mStrings = new ArrayList<String>() {{
                add("None");
                add("one");
                add("two");
                add("three");
            }};
            mStringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(mStringArrayAdapter);
            mSpinner.setSelection(0);
            mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String string = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    if (!string.equals("None"))
                        removeThisFromSpinner(string);
                    mSpinner.setSelection(0);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


        }

        private void removeThisFromSpinner(String s) {
            mStrings.remove(s);
            mStringArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Comment: If I want to disable it and  not to delete it?

Comment: Instead of removing item, put the string in HashMap so the string will not be duplicated.

Comment: How I am going to do it here ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope it helps :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onItemSelected: "+position);
//checking the position of the selected spinner item, if the previous position is not the same then do something here
                    if(position>0 && position!=myPosition){

                    }
                   myPosition = position;



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

and don't forget to add global variable to the class :

```
int myPosition = 999; // the non existed position make it global variable
```